# applying direction to npc XNA

Tags: c#, matrix, xna, rotation

I have NPC's in my game that follow a script where they move randomly around the game. I would like them to face the direction they are moving in though.

```
for (int i = 0; i < GameConstants.NumDaleks; i++)
{
    if (dalekList[i].isActive)
    {
        Vector3 line = dalekList[i].direction;
        float rotationDal = (float)(Math.Atan2(dalekList[i].position.Y, dalekList[i].position.X) / (2 * Math.PI));

        Matrix dalekTransform = Matrix.CreateScale(GameConstants.DalekScalar) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(rotationDal) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(dalekList[i].position);
        DrawModel(mdlDalek, dalekTransform, mdDalekTransforms);
     }
}
```

I'm sure it must be something to do with rotationDal, I have tried changing the calculation and the characters do seem to rotate differently, just not in their current direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xna has a built in function that you might find handy here.

```
Matrix.CreateWorld(positionVector, DirectionVector, UpVector);
```

here's the doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975261(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx

In your case:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GameConstants.NumDaleks; i++)
{
    if (dalekList[i].isActive)
    {
        Matrix dalekTransform = Matrix.CreateScale(GameConstants.DalekScalar) * Matrix.CreateWorld(dalekList[i].position, dalekList[i].direction, Vector3.Up);
        DrawModel(mdlDalek, dalekTransform, mdDalekTransforms);
     }
}
```